# Eclipse->Prefrences->Network connections

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse network connection, i need to select 'Active Provider' as 'Native' and add some proxy entries. But i am unable to do so. There is nothing to add proxy entries and its not picking the entries from web browser.
 Pls help.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7625943/632951 too

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse's Network Connections is depends on your Local Area Network (LAN) Settings.

For Windows, go to `Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN settings` and add `address` and `port` of your favourite proxy server, then restart your Eclipse.