# Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Tags: eclipse

I was trying to add the PDT,

Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo.
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo is not a valid repository location.

So what's the correct url ? I went and looked lots of places. Can someone point me to the exact link ?

**Edit** :

Problem once you go to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo , you will see the below error. So I guess its moved somewhere.

> This software repository URL, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ , provides access to the software repository for the Eclipse indigo release. Until its released in June 2011, it will contain milestone builds.
>
> The repository site URL is typically pre-populated in the list of software repositories when you install the Eclipse Platform or SDK.
>
> For more information about installing or updating software, see the Eclipse Platform Help.
>
> There is also a collection of handy, downloadable all-in-one zip files available for many interests and platforms. Many people find these all-in-one packages the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Can you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?

- Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser.
- Look up any normal adress, is it working?

Can you connect to another update site? Try for example Eclipse Emma:
http://update.eclemma.org/
Do you see anything there?

What are your proxy preferences? Go to Window -> preferences -> General: Network connections.

The active provider:

> Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections. Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened without the use of a proxy server. Selecting Manual causes settings defined in Eclipse to be used. **On some platforms there is also a Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used.**

If internet is working fine outside of Eclipse, try changing to Native. After that, try Direct.

I have encountered problems where an update site would not load, then I had to remove it and add it again. This forces Eclipse to reread the contents of the site even if it has a cached copy. So, if you still get no connection to the indigo update site, but everything else is working, try that. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site. Just remember to copy the adress so you can add it again.

As suggested in a comment below by @lostiniceland, this is a simpler way to achieve the above:

*Goto Window -> Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry and click the "Reload" button to the right. This is sometimes also helpful when you have a local updatesite for testing custom plugins*

Comment: Thank you @Fredrik . You are exactly correct . I was able to browse via internal broswer and you also teached me something new. Defnitly the boundy is for you. Thank you once again.

Comment: I just had the same problem with Eclipse Classic 3.7.2. When the it is not due to the proxy then you have to reload the updatesite. Goto Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry and click the "Reload" button to the right. This is sometimes also helpful when you have a local updatesite for testing custom plugins.

Comment: @lostiniceland Yes, that button is fairly new I think, this wasn't an option in earlier versions. I'll add that suggestion.

Comment: In my case the above procedure didn't help until I opened the Internet explorer and saw that the proxy settings were not set, although internet was working. 
I have set correct proxy settings in IE and only then in Eclipse Network connection settings the new fields appeared, as: 
Native HTTP proxy ...etc
Entering correct proxy settings in Manual provider in eclipse network settings didn't help.

Comment: I can connect to any web page address.

Comment: this part did the trick for me: Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site..THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!

Comment: @Fredrik, If "native causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used", does that mean "native" is faster or "direct"?

Comment: I am facing the same error with Eclipse Luna - "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/". I have verified that proxy settings are not set and also not required. I can browse to this URL from the Internal Web Browser. But when I try this in "Install New Software", then getting the error "Unable to read repository...".

Comment: i have the same problem with eclipse indigo , but nothing worked for me

Comment: Following this advice, I found I was unable to connect to any web page. The solution for me was to download new security certificates for Java. That is, I replaced the cacerts file with one from my company. My cacerts file was at 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\security\cacerts

Comment: @MeladBasilius Same here! I didn't use update sites for years... and now nothing works (except the http://update.eclemma.org referenced here). Still using Eclipse 3.8

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem and resolved it by

- Deleting the cache directory `\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache`
- Refreshing the repositories.

  - Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry
  - Click the "Reload"

Comment: This works for me as well, save my couple of hours, very Thanks !

Comment: Hi, please where can I find this path? `\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache`

Comment: whereever eclipse is installed. Inside it you will find p2 and then the rest

Comment: I did that. Same problem... Unable to read repository at https://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml.
Connection reset

Answer (score 9):

Check if you are able to connect to eclipse market place url (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) from browser. If its working then the issue is because of proxy server using in your network.
We have to update eclipse with proxy server details used in our network.

Go to :- Windows-> Preference -> General -> Network Connections.

[image]

And edit HTTP ,with proxy details.

[image]

Click OK

Done.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem and it turned out to be our firewall. It has some very general functions for blocking ActiveX, Java, etc., and the Java functionality was blocking the jar downloads as Eclipse attempted them.

The firewall was returning an html page explaining that the content was blocked, which of course went unseen. Thank goodness for Wireshark :)

Comment: I just disabled the Windows Firewall and it worked !

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve this kind of error is to start eclipse with this argument

**-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**

Working fine with Eclipse (x64) 4.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem in Linux, and I found that the user doesn't have permission to update the eclipse directory

change the owner of eclipse folder recursively, or run eclipse with user who has write permission to the folder

Comment: Finally! I have spent hours tracking down networking issues, but this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 32-bit version, I started the eclipse with as an administrator. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try to deactivate your Firewall (I had avast!), which worked for me.

(Sorry for my English I'm French :D)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using correct url. If You are using url - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo on your eclipse luna(v4.4) then it might be not working in this case you should use - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna

I have tried this and its working.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to [@Fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207764/fredrik) above.  His [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722815/4151626) didn't work for me, but lead me to the resolution of my issue:

In 'Window'|'Preferences'|'Install/Update'|'Available Software Sites'.  The location that I was attempting to install from the 'Marketplace' was getting inserted with an `https://` URL.  Editing this to `http://` allowed me to then use 'Help'|Install New Software ...' to select the repository from the drop down 'Work with:' combobox instead of having the `https://` one automatically inserted and used.
[image]

Comment: ooops. Could some moderator please undo my changes to this answer. I reverted to how the answer was. I accidentally edited this answer, thinking it was my answer. When I realized, I changed back what I thought I had added. Would be cleaner though, if the moderators could reset and remove my changes altogether, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

Since yesterday, I have been trying to install the Eclipse plugin - "Remote System Explorer" from the Eclipse marketplace on a freshly downloaded Eclipse 4.8 as shown below,

[image]

and everytime I was getting this error:

> Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/.
>   Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201306260900/content.jar.
>   download.eclipse.org:80 failed to respond

which brought me to this SO post.

I tried a few solutions mentioned here in the different answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722815/2955790) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750289/2955790) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25423180/2955790), but none of them worked. I just gave up almost, thinking that either the corporate network here is somehow blocking the specific download requests or the 4.8 version of Eclipse is buggy.

**Discovery:**

I could not reload *all* the paths under `'Window' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Install/Update' -> 'Available Software Sites'`.

[image: http reload fails]

**Preconditions:**

- What did work for me from the beginning was:

  1. I could open [google.com](https://google.com) from the *internal web browser* of eclipse and,
  2. some of the update paths, I could reload even. (As was mentioned as a possible solution or test, in some of the answers here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750289/2955790).)

Finally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119914/2955790) put me on the right track - for my specific case, at least. Just my step was to do the exact opposite of what that answer was doing.

**Solution:**

I had to change all the `http:\\` paths to `https:\\` and suddenly it started to work. I don't know who - either IE/Edge on Windows 10 or the Windows 10 firewall or the company firewall is blocking HTTP communications. But with HTTPS, I can finally install plugins from the Marketplace.

- HTTPS reload works
  [image]

I must say, what is strange is that not all the paths required `https`. Except a few, the rest seemed to have had no problem working with `HTTP`. But I anyways changed all to `HTTPS`, just for good measure.

[image]

- Then reload all the repositories one by one. Press "Apply and close".
- Then check for updates. Eclipse will update itself successfully now.
- Restart after update.
- Finally you can install whichever Plugin you would like to from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Note: In case during the update, this same error pops up again, then see in the repositories that any new paths added by eclipse during the update, are also HTTPS and not HTTP.

Comment: I had to do both using the oomph installer. For http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e411/releases/3.x. it had to be https, for https://dl.bintray.com/fraenkelc/buildship3_setuptask/updates it had to be http.

Comment: I am glad it helped. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse, there are normally different options available:

- If you want to use the PHP development environment (only), you should go with the corresponding distro of eclipse. There is a [distro for PHP](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt) provided by Zend.
- You may add PDT to an indigo release by doing the following steps:

  - Check if an update site for PDT is included in your eclipse installation:

    1. Open the `Help > Install New Software` dialog.
    2. Click there on the link `Available Software Sites`.
    3. In the list, the URL http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo should be marked.
    4. Close the dialog.
  - Select from the `Work with` list the site with the right URL.
  - Enter in the filter box `PDT` and search in the list for the PDT tooling you want to install.
    [image]
  - Install the PDT tooling.
- If that does not work, you may download a complete update site from the PDT project site.

  1. Visit the site (URL above).
  2. Click on downloads.
  3. Search there for the string "all in one update site".
  4. Download the zip file.
  5. Install it in your Indigo installation. `Help > Install New Software > Add... > Enter name and select from button Archive the zip file`

I hope some of the installation instructions will work for you.

Comment: Yes you are right, but when I went to see the url with the browser http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ I am seeing `This software repository URL, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ , provides access to the software repository for the Eclipse indigo release. Until its released in June 2011, it will contain milestone builds.` . As I have installed Java already for trying the Android, I want to add PDT for PHP, so I can remove netbeans .

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct URL. Chances are Eclipse cannot read it properly because of the Internet connexion.

Are you using a proxy to get Internet access? If this is the case you need to notify Eclipse via the "Preferences/General/Network Connections" menu.

Comment: No once you go to the url you can see `This software repository URL, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ , provides access to the software repository for the Eclipse indigo release. Until its released in June 2011, it will contain milestone builds.....` . So I am wondering

Comment: I am not using any proxy. Just dialing with my CDMA device. Wondering many people have already asked about the proxy.

Comment: @Hari Weird indeed. Which version of Eclipse are you using? Is this an old version?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes really wired. I have downloaded some weeks back. Not sure other than I can see Indigo. Any other I want to try. From Help-> About . Its indigo .

Answer (score 0):

That URL works fine. The message you report is normal when you look at it in a browser. My copy of Eclipse has no problems talking to it. If yours does, I suspect a proxy configuration error in your copy of eclipse.

Comment: What should I change then for the proxy ? I am dialing directly with the device. Just dial and I can browse . So I am not adding any proxy to my Browser too ..............

Answer (score 0):

Also try it by turning off the firewall, and similar services. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ simply
try to use http://
instead of https://

Comment: Note that the question was about Eclipse, not Android ADT.

Comment: you are wonderful, thank you. Was struggling to fix an error with mybatise-code generator and eclipse was give some crazy certificate error, changing https to http really really really worked..

Answer (score 0):

I spent whole my day figuring out this and found the following. And it works great now.

This is basically an issue with your gateway or proxy, If you are under proxy network, Please go to the network settings and set the proxy server settings(server, port , user name and password). If you are under direct gateway network, your firewall may be blocking the http get request from your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to read the repository. Even after the disabling most of the entries under *Available Software Sites* things were still not working.

I had no proxy to worry about and even disabling the firewall (which I do not recommended) as a last resort did not help.

Viewing the error log, from the dialog box which Eclipse displayed, there was mention of a cache directory under .eclipse in my home directory. I deleted the two cache directories I found and Eclipse was working again.

For my setup the two directories I deleted were:

.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2_119745494_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/cache

.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2_119745494_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache

NB: My setup is Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 running on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered that the major issue why my eclipse won't connect to internet is my Internet Service Provider. I was only able to browse some websites but unable to browse other website. Fixing the issue with the ISP worked.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the Eclipse Marketplace client needed updating.

After trying Fredriks solution of

> Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site. Just remember to copy the adress so you can add it again.

The Marketplace client wouldn't load. But  I could access it via a browser.
So, I went to the Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
it loaded fine

Clicked on Installed and found the Eclipse Marketplace Client and it had  so i clicked it it updated and then when I did the standard update everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there will be firewalls and restrictions in the network preventing the plugin to get downloaded. We can try some other network. This actually resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue while adding team explorer plugin to eclipse from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere.
Used team explorer plugin for ecplise for internal use of xamarin for mac.

Error:
unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.provisionexception unable to read repository
Unknown host exception

Goto https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases
Download: TFSEclipsePlugin-UpdateSiteArchive-14.135.0.zip
From Eclipse->Help->Install new software.
From Add Repository window select **Archive** select the downloaded zip file.
Continue installation.

Answer (score -1):

Also try if in the eclipse paths there is some duplicated 
Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/1234567...

Try both of them, one may work.

In my case, with 2 eclispes installed, in one of them the path
Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna

works, in the other one, i must select:
Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/123456...

In both the internal browser can access to internet. Both are Luna (but one is RCM, the other one i don't remember).

Answer (score -4):

No meu caso era o anti-vírus que estava bloqueando a conexão do eclipse, desativei o anti-víruse tudo funcionou o//.

**Translation:** 
In my case it was the anti-virus that was blocking the connection from eclipse. I disabled the anti-virus and everything worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is expected that you answer questions with formal english. The same applies if you ask a question. Besides, you should be able to configure your anti-virus without needing to block eclipse connection. Put more effort in your answer x)