# Eclipse can not connect to internet

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.6. I am trying to download a plug in from an update site, but it won't connect, it keeps saying "Pending" for quite some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not alot of information there. It helps to let us know what you have tried...

I'll quote an [answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo/7722815#7722815) to a similar question, which contains the basic workarounds:

---

Can you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?

Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser. Look up any normal adress, is it working?

Can you connect to another update site? Try for example Eclipse Emma: http://update.eclemma.org/ Do you see anything there?

What are your proxy preferences? Go to Window -> preferences -> General: Network connections.

The active provider:

> Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections. Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened without the use of a proxy server. Selecting Manual causes settings defined in Eclipse to be used. On some platforms there is also a Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used.

If internet is working fine outside of Eclipse, try changing to Native. After that, try Direct.

Comment: It appears to be working. It seems it was a problem on the connection.

Comment: @Fredrik I am having the same problem of not being able to connect to the internet in eclipse (both kepler and helios) on SLES 11. I tried to change the Active provider to Native and Direct but it still does not work..Any other thing that I should try ?

Comment: @Ragini Sorry, not really. If internet works outside of eclipe and direct or native doesn't work I would look into firewall issues. Perhaps your Eclipse program is prevented from contacting internet at all.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one more option to try if none of the efforts above helped. **You might be using Eclipse from a Shared Drive (for eg, H:)**. If so, move/copy it the entire Eclipse directory to C: and try again.

My Eclipse could not connect to internet, nor access Eclipse Marketplace, nor even open ports for Tomcat server. I am behind a corporate proxy and tried many options that I have found on Stack Overflow and other forums but to no avail. I've also tried different versions (Mars, Luna, Kepler and a corporate-provided Kepler).

These are the options I have tried:

**Use Direct Connection**

- Go to Windows > Perferences > General > Network Connections.
- Change Active Provider to Direct.
- Restart Eclipse.

**Set up Manual Proxy**

- Go to Windows > Perferences > General > Network Connections.
- Change Active Provider to Manual.
- Input proxy details, including username/password if required.
- Clear SOCKS proxy.
- Restart Eclipse.

**Change Eclipse.ini**

- Go to Windows > Perferences > General > Network Connections.
- Change Active Provider to Native.
- Open Eclipse.ini.

Add the following under `-vmargs`, each on its own line.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy
-Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

- Restart Eclipse

See:

- [Unable to connect to the Eclipse Luna Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148782/unable-to-connect-to-the-eclipse-luna-market)
- [How do I configure the proxy settings so eclipse indigo can install new plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298655/how-do-i-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-indigo-can-install-new-plugins)
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient
- See answer by Ruhr Dev on Thu, 29 December 2011: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/

**Add Eclipse to Firewall**

- Go to Control Panel > Windows Firewall (or your own firewall)
- Add Eclipse to whitelist (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508990 for Windows Firewall)

**Delete Oomph-releated sub folders**

- Delete all Oomph-releated sub folders in ${user.home}/.eclipse/ folder
- For Windows this may be in C:\Users\.eclipse

See answer by Stephan EberleFriend on Fri, 14 August 2015 18:54: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/

See my other answer for Eclipse not able to open ports for Tomcat (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246227/4212710).

Answer (score 0):

If eclipse could not able to connect to internet, following **may be** one of the reason:
There is a service called "Network Access Protection Agent", which might be blocking eclipse from accessing the internet.

In this case, you can try the following (this worked for me-Windows 7 PC):
1. Click on Windows Start button and search for Administrative Tools and Open it
2. Then open Services
3. Look for "Network Access Protection Agent" service
4. Stop this service
5. Now eclipse should be able to connect to internet

Note: This happens when Windows are not up to date. So after stopping this service, update your Windows, then start this service.