# How do I configure the proxy settings so eclipse indigo can install new plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, proxy

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin), but didn't work in my case.

I'm using eclipse indigo SR1 in a linux Fedora 32 bits. It's virtualized by VMWare Player. All applications in this linux is working when I configure the proxy settings but eclipse. I'm getting this errors that appears to be well known.

I have found [This](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281472#c7) solution that I've tried in my enviroment, but didn't work. When I configure settings in eclipse.ini and launch eclipse, I get errors in the log like this:

```
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost has been set to 8080 by an external resource. This value will be overwritten using the values from preferences.
```

How can I force eclipse to prefer configurations in eclipse.ini instead of preferences panel?

Have somebody any insight?

Best regards.

Comment: If you really don't want to configure it through the preferences panel, there is a workaround to allow Eclipse to infer your system settings (http://cateof.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/eclipse-galileo-proxy-problem-workaround-solution/).

Comment: I have tested and it didn't work for me. :(

Answer (score 11):

```
You need to specify the following options below the -vmargs option in the .ini file, each on a separate line:
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy
-Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Btw, are you behind an HTTP proxy or some other proxy? and why doesnt preferences menu work for you?

Try adding this line to .ini file if above arguments dont work:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
```

Comment: I'm behind a http proxy. With preferences panel, I'm getting error "Authentatication Requerid" as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

Ayushman's answer helped me but after that I am still unable to install software from eclipse market place.
I got one link after that I can install software from eclipse marketplace.
[Click here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t45492.html)

This works fine for unauthenticated HTTP proxy requests. However, if you have a proxy that requires authentication (typical for sites where Kerberos is installed and/or Active Directory, or where network security is paranoid) then this method doesn't work.

If you set the JVM's proxy to use the same settings as IE, the proxy request will automatically pass the security credentials, as long as you've browsed the web with IE first (and thus the security token has already been obtained).

Steps to set JVM proxy:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Programs
3. Java
4. General tab
5. "Network Settings" button
6. Select the radio button for "Use Proxy Server"
7. Give your proxy address and port number (usually 8080)
8. Click OK

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and I tried different solutions mentioned here and in several blogs without having one working to me.

However... one solution I found is that if you have an x32 Eclipse IDE, and an x64 OS, setting will not always save, and you may face these problems.

I had this problem with *Juno x32* + *Win7 x64*, now it's solved using *Juno x64*, and *Kepler x64*

So, check your OS/IDE and make sure that you have the right versions.