# Eclipse not connecting to internet via proxy

Tags: eclipse, proxy, java

My eclipse(juno 4.2, centos 5.6) doesn't connect to internet. At all. I have a proxy server setup.

I had a look at [Eclipse can not connect to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778484/eclipse-can-not-connect-to-internet)
and at various other questions. So, at the moment, my eclipse.ini file looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.1.21
-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I also tried setting proxy server values in the preferences(preferences/Network Connections) - set the HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS host, port & credentials. But none of the Active Provider settings(Manual, Native, Direct) work for me.

I've spent enough time on this to know that I need help. Badly. :P

So, here I am...help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this through the preferences UI, under the 'Network Connection' section. I had to set 'Active Provider' to 'Manual' & then provide proxy server details below that.

Comment: Still Eclipse is not recognizing the Proxy (on Linux)

Answer (score 1):

This post ([Eclipse Kepler not connecting to internet via proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338212/eclipse-kepler-not-connecting-to-internet-via-proxy)) suggests that you shouldn't set (or you should reset to blank) the SOCKS proxy for the network connection to actually work. Did you try this ?

EDIT : maybe I'm a tad late :) But it still could work for other people

Comment: Yes, I tried leaving them blank, hoping eclipse would pick it up from the environment. But that did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing this problem after using cntlm and socks settings; your anti virus program may be the cause.
I tried every suggestion I found, however I could not connect to the internet in marketplace (i.e. When I activated cntlm I could connect to the internet using web browser, but cannot connect through eclipse or maven). Then figured out anti virus program was blocking.