# Can't access Eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I can't seem to access the Eclipse marketplace. I'm using Juno 4.2. I tried deleting eclipse and removing all plugins, deleting my .metadata, and deleting the eclipse app data.

I've tried switching my default browser from firefox to chrome, I've tried turning on and completely off Windows firewall. I'm at home.

I was able to get eclipse updates, though. When I try to report a bug for the marketplace I get a different error.

When I try to connect, I receive quite a few errors.

First one is a warning:

```
Connection to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p failed on Connection reset. Retry attempt 0 started
```

Second is an error:

```
Cannot install remote marketplace locations.:
```

Third is another error:

```
Unexpected exception
```

Here are the stack traces in order received:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$GzipGetMethod.execute(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1129)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$3.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)


java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$3.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$3.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:200)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$GzipGetMethod.execute(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1129)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    ... 11 more


java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.discovery.wizards.CatalogViewer.updateCatalog(CatalogViewer.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceViewer.updateCatalog(MarketplaceViewer.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplacePage$6.run(MarketplacePage.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.Catalog.performDiscovery(Catalog.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceCatalog.performDiscovery(MarketplaceCatalog.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.discovery.wizards.CatalogViewer$6.run(CatalogViewer.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Considering this as a *general* programming problem, some possible causes are:

- The service could be temporarily broken
- You could have a problem with a firewall.  These could be local or they could be implemented by your ISPs.
- Your proxy HTTP settings (if you need one) could be incorrect.  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25337453/139985) explains how to adjust the Eclipse-internal proxy settings ... if that is where the problem lies.
- It is possible that your access may be blocked by over-active antivirus software.
- The service could have blacklisted some net range and your hosts IP address is "collateral damage".

Try connecting to that URL with a web browser to try to see if it is just Eclipse that is affected ... or a broader problem.

---

Considering this in the context of the Eclipse Marketplace service, first address any local proxy / firewall / AV issues, if they apply.  If that doesn't help, the best thing that you can do is to be patient.

- It has been observed that the Eclipse Marketplace service **does** sometimes go down.  It doesn't happen often, and when it does happen the problem does get fixed relatively quickly.  (Hours, not days ...)
- I can't find a "service status" page or feed or similar for the Eclipse services.  (If you know of one, please add it as a comment below.)
- There may be an "outage" notice on the Eclipse front page.  Check for that.
- Try to connect to the service URL (refer to the exception message!) using a web browser and/or from other locations.  If you succeed, the real problem may be a networking issue at your end.
- If you feel the need to complain about Eclipse's services, *please don't do it here!!*  (It is off topic.)

Comment: Looks like I cannot connect to that URL with Firefox. I used to be able to connect to the marketplace just fine, but I feel like a couple weeks ago I started having this issue. But maybe I'm misremembering and the service is just down ...

Comment: Service temporarily broken.

Comment: @TomBrito - So wait a few hours.  It will come back.

Answer (score 65):

**Here's the solution,**

*If you are a constant proxy changer like me for various reasons (university, home , workplace and so on..) you are mostly likely to get this error due to improper configuration of connection  settings in the eclipse IDE. all you have to do it play around with the current settings and get it to working state. Here's how,,*

**1. GO TO**

Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.

**2. Change the Settings**

Active Provider-> Manual-> and check---> HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS

If your active provider is already set to Manual, try restoring the default (native)

---

> That's all, restart Eclipse and you are good to go!

---

Comment: For me, it works to show the initial list of items on the Marketplace. After I click on a different tab or try to search then the error message is back

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to set the proxy to "native" as below

Go to "Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection" and change the Settings "Active Provider-> Native". It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you're able to successfully load a page from Eclipses internal web browser (by going to "Window"=>"Show View"=>"Other"=>"Internal Web Browser" and trying to open a page) **BUT** installing software from the eclipse marketplace and the "Help"=>"Install New Software" window are not working then this fix may help you (worked for me on a Windows 7 machine):

1. Go to "Window"=>"Preferences"=>"General"=>"Network Connections" and set the Active Provider to "Native".
2. Go into the Windows Control pannel and search firewall. Then select "Allow Program Through Windows Firewall" and click "Allow Other Program..." and add your eclipse installation.

[image]
[image]

3. Restart Eclipse and try refreshing a repository on the "Help"=>"Install New Software" window. It was able to successfull grab it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the folder where eclipse is installed

```
open eclipse.ini file
look for the line -vmargs
put -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true below the -vmargs line and restart eclipse
```

Comment: One simple sentence made my day. Thanks

Comment: Simple and quick fix and it worked. Other options didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and found here useful steps which saved my time a lot.
Hope so below attached image will help you a lot-

**Window-> Preferences-> General-> Network Connection**

Change Active Provider Native to Manual if problem is not resolved by using the steps mentioned in snapshot.
Make sure HTTP/HTTPS should be checked and if any IP is required for your proxy settings then you should provide proxy IP in host and port number as well.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

in my case: i got a new pc and I had to download and install a brand new eclipse. by default the proxy was set to native. I was getting that error at first. I then changed it to active. And still it didn't work. And then i put it back to "native" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the solution was to set the proxy to "native"
I had configured the proxy under linux with cntlm and also in Firefox (used as eclipse browser also.

Answer (score 0):

And also check with your antivirus, in case of me its avast, its blocking me from accessing market place, so i disabled it for few mins and tried accessing market place from eclipse , it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Im my case, I changed the default browser to internet explorer from google chrome and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old but I ran in the same problem today. I wanted to install eclipse on my vm with xubuntu. Because I've had problems with the latest eclipse version 2019-06 I tried with Oxygen. So I went to eclipse.org and downloaded oxygen. When running oxygen, the problem with merketplace not reachable occurs. So I downloaded the eclipse installer not immediatly the oxygen. After that I can use eclipse as expectet ( all versions)