# Unable to connect to the Eclipse Luna Market

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I cant connect my Eclipse Luna distribution to the market for install Maven 2 pluggin. This my configuration :

Eclipse :
- Eclipse Luna M5 Release, I configured a proxy

My computer :
- Windows XP 32bits

this is the error message :

```
!SESSION 2014-03-03 14:55:53.568 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140123-1600
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-03-03 14:56:01.676
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be <myProxy_url>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-03-03 14:56:01.692
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be <myProxy_port>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-03-03 14:56:01.692
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be <myProxy_url>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-03-03 14:56:01.692
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be <myProxy_port>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-03-03 14:56:01.692
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be <myProxy_url>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-03-03 14:56:01.708
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be <myProxy_port>.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui 4 0 2014-03-03 14:56:14.988
!MESSAGE Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1122)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 400.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    ... 12 more
Contains: Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 400.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui 4 0 2014-03-03 14:56:14.988
!MESSAGE Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 400.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    ... 12 more
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2014-03-03 14:56:14.988
!MESSAGE Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 400.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.ecf.identity 4 0 2014-03-03 14:56:14.988
!MESSAGE HttpComponents connection error response code 400.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2014-03-03 14:56:14.988
!MESSAGE Bad HTTP Request: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 400.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.ecf.identity 4 0 2014-03-03 14:56:14.988
!MESSAGE HttpComponents connection error response code 400.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-03 14:56:17.457
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-03 14:56:17.472
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Documents and Settings\ombinte'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: Does the hostname "evy01-proxy.eu.accor.net" make any sense to you?

Comment: It's the url of proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't access Eclipse marketplace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794885/cant-access-eclipse-marketplace)

Comment: Here is the contemporary solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204939/715269. (starting from 4.3 version). The other answer there works for older versions.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I found a solution. I changed my Eclipse version. I use Eclipse Indigo now because all 4.x version not work on my computer. For reminder i use a Windows XP 32bits...a prehistorics machine.

Comment: I don't think that downgrade Eclipse is the best solution. In general, downgrade anything is a last resort because you're missing fixes, updates, etc.

Answer (score 46):

With some proxy servers there appears to be a problem with the HttpClient libraries used by Eclipse 4.4. The workaround is to use the JRE http client by putting this line in eclipse.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

[Eclipse bug discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422665)

[Disabling Apache HttpClient](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient)

Comment: Correct argument for eclipse 4.3 or greater confguration will be `-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4` with 4 at the end. But thanks! This works for me.

Comment: I tried by installing this software http://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/httpclient4/org.eclipse.ecf.provider.httpclient4_3.9.0.zip, restarted eclipse as mentioned by a poster in the 'Eclipse bug discussion' and it worked.

Comment: @SyAu: Seems like Proxy authentication goes away after this installation. However, installation of heavier plugins like one for Grails still breaks in the middle throwing bunch of read timeout errors.

Answer (score 5):

I tried every thing it did't work out for me..Finaly i found out that ,you have to allow eclipse from windows firewall(Windows 7).

->go to control panel>system and security>windows Firewall>Allow program or feature through windows firewall

->Then browse eclipse.exe

->Restart eclipse

Answer (score 3):

**1. GO TO**

Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.

**2. Change the Settings**

Active Provider-> Manual-> and check---> HTTP, HTTPS and SOCS

**Restart Eclipse and ENJOY!**

Answer (score 2):

On linux64, I had similar issues with luna, whereas Kepler connects fine. 
I saw somewhere that you should clear SOCKS entry in Network connections and be in manual Active Provider.
Then restart Eclipse to apply changes.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I had similar problem with luna in ubuntu 64 and clearing the socks entry in network proxy of the system works like a charm. :)

Comment: Same story with Neon. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

just add this line in your eclipse.ini

```
Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

and restart eclipse!

if it persist , check the parameters of network connections in `Tools > preferences > general > Network connections`