# How to configure Eclipse Market place in Spring Tool Suite 3.8.1-64?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

In spring Tool suite there is no tab for Eclipse Market Place to search any new plugin for install..so i am trying to configure eclipse market place in my sts IDE

Below is the step:

1) go to help

2) select Install New Software Tab

3) After that i am getting window for location select but what location i have to put for market place configure in sts
i try with different kind of location from google but not any work for sts 
so anyone having idea regarding this solution then please suggest?

Comment: Do you have the option Help>Eclipse Marketplace...?

Comment: No i do not have that option in my STS IDE ..and i want to add that option

Comment: It's probably still there.Just hidden by sts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this as a *general* programming problem, some possible causes are:

- The service could be temporarily broken
- You could have a problem with a firewall.  These could be local or they could be implemented by your ISPs.
- Your proxy HTTP settings (if you need one) could be incorrect.  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25337453/139985) explains how to adjust the Eclipse-internal proxy settings ... if that is where the problem lies.
- It is possible that your access may be blocked by over-active antivirus software.
- The service could have blacklisted some net range and your hosts IP address is "collateral damage".

Try connecting to that URL with a web browser to try to see if it is just Eclipse that is affected ... or a broader problem.

---

Considering this in the context of the Eclipse Marketplace service, first address any local proxy / firewall / AV issues, if they apply.  If that doesn't help, the best thing that you can do is to be patient.

- It has been observed that the Eclipse Marketplace service **does** sometimes go down.  It doesn't happen often, and when it does happen the problem does get fixed relatively quickly.  (Hours, not days ...)
- I can't find a "service status" page or feed or similar for the Eclipse services.  (If you know of one, please add it as a comment below.)
- There may be an "outage" notice on the Eclipse front page.  Check for that.
- Try to connect to the service URL (refer to the exception message!) using a web browser and/or from other locations.  If you succeed, the real problem may be a networking issue at your end.
- If you feel the need to complain about Eclipse's services, *please don't do it here!!*  (It is off topic.)