# Eclipse - Downloading content.jar.. times out while installing plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am using `Eclipse Indigo (3.7)` and facing issues while installing plugins onto it. Following are the steps I followed:

```
1. Add the download site
2. Select the plugin to be installed
3. Clicked on Next - Eclipse shows 'Calculating requirements and dependencies'
4. It shows Fetching content.jar from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201106220900/content.jar
5. After running for some 5 mins it shows 'Read timed out'. Error reading from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201106220900/content.jar
```

Note that I have a good internet connectivity. And I am able to download the file manually from browser but eclipse is facing issues in downloading from internet. Does anyone know how to avoid this problem?

`Platform:` Windows7 x64; Eclipse Indigo SR1

Comment: Had the same problem for several days.
Solved by disabling AVG.

Comment: excellent. had the problem with any plugin on 2 diff pcs with AVG... fixed with disabling it.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The answer here was useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722815/2912901

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After googling for couple of hours(!), I did the following:

1. Plugin installation will be faster if we disable the `Contact all update sites during install to find the required software` checkbox. This was causing eclipse to contact *all* update sites to find the plugin.
2. Disabled AVG 2012 for sometime. Seems like this was causing problems to eclipse while downloading content from internet http://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=175473

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was Kaspersky for me thanks! +1 Really strange, since only for Spring Source tool gave me that error

Comment: If you don't have the option of disabling your antivirus, you can download the plugin externally and install (described in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip), but make sure to do #1 above, disable the `Contact all update sites during install to find the required software` checkbox. Also check the Progress view and cancel any In Progress downloads.