# Unable to download ADT Plugin for Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (ver 3.7) on Win 7 (64 bit).
I have been trying to download ADT plugin for the past 2 days but unable to do so.
I've tried both Https and Http versions of https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but to no avail. Downloaded the .zip file for the ADT plugin locally and tried but it kept saying 'org.eclipse...wst.o.o.o' could not be found. 
To correct the problem as suggested by some, I tried to update Indigo but the initial download of contents.jar from the repository is timing out. Following is the error:

Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201106220900/content.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at file:/C:/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/content-2092920409.jar.
Premature end of file.

Please help!
P.S.: Have also tried running eclipse as an administrator.

Comment: Also have been trying to update Eclipse but halfway through the check i get the following error:
Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at file:/C:/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/content919885352.jar.
Premature end of file.
Unable to read repository at file:/C:/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/content-2092920409.jar.
Premature end of file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. Tried all those solutions then ran

> sudo eclipse

in my ubuntu; the normal method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my case the problem was my antivirus and my firewall, this link helped me

[Eclipse - Downloading content.jar.. times out while installing plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367856/eclipse-downloading-content-jar-times-out-while-installing-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have write permission on the android SDK tree. Either use root to configure eclipse and install the plugin or chown -R  .