# Java Eclipse IDE - Repository Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, repository

I've been up for hours now, searching online for a solution. I can happily say, this has really pissed me off.

Upon opening 'Install New Software' I get "'Contacting Software Sites' has encountered a problem.

Some sites could now be found. See the error log for more detail."

Here's the error log:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>   Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo/content.xml.
>   Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/content.xml. Cannot
>   assign requested address: JVM_Bind Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/indigo/content.xml. Cannot
>   assign requested address: JVM_Bind Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml. Cannot assign
>   requested address: JVM_Bind

Any ideas?
I want to install MercurialEclipse but it cannot find the repository, same for the defaults.

Comment: are you behind a proxy server??? may be the problem is with proxy settings

Comment: What version of eclipse and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy server. I'm running Windows 7 and Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't get it. This dude here was having the same problem, but no one replied: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/718688/. Seems to be an issue with the latest Eclipse. I'm on Mac OSX Lion.

Answer (score 64):

I had the same problem. And found solution on russia site.
In file eclipse.ini under line **-vmargs** add this line:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

This will resolve problem.

[Site with explanation](http://drfits.com/2011/11/13/eclipse-contacting-software-sites-has-encountered-a-problem/)

Comment: THIS is the solution. Somebody mark this as the answer. Encountered the same weird bug today, followed this advice, worked like a charm.

Comment: Never had this problem with Indigo on Linux, or with Juno M7, but for some reason when I upgraded to the release Juno I was unable to download plugins from the release repository (the updates repository, however, worked fine). This solved the problem!

Comment: I am using Vista and eclipse Juno and JUnit4 - this solved my problems, it is the only place on the internet i found the answer, i wish i had rights to flag this as the answer - it is important to others to save them search time

Comment: Sadly the linked page is now offline

Comment: @MattQuiros this is not the answer. If you were to try to open that in your native web browser (not Eclipse's internal browser), there is no file there. It makes no difference how the JVM starts if the URL doesn't resolve to anything.

Answer (score 15):

I have encountered the same problem. I have resolved disabling the site using:

**Window** → **Preferences** → **Install/Update** → **Available software Site**

Here the site that can be used have a tick (enabled). You must find the site that caused the problems and disabled them.

I hope this could be useful.

Comment: This worked for me. The suggested answer by JS still gave me the same error message after I added the line.

Comment: By unpicking it you are now not checking for those updates.  That makes the error go away, but now you will not find updates for those components.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by disabling the `McAffee Host Intrusion Detection` program during the installation.

I noticed an additional symptom that I wasn't able to browse the Internet using the **Eclipse Internal Web Browser** feature using below Eclipse Menu navigational steps:

```
  Window → Show View → Other → General → Internal Web Browser.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem in the past when installing new software in Eclipse.

In my case it has always been a problem with my Eclipse Proxy settings.

Eclipse > Preferences > General > Network Connections

Make sure you have your proxy settings configured correctly. If you are on a college or office network you can get the Proxy details of the administrator. In my case I had to configure the HTTP, HTTPS and the SOCKS.

The SOCKS requires that you input your username and password.

**NOTE: If your network username or password changes you will have to update this.**

In my case I had to change the "Active Provider" drop down from 'Direct' to 'Manual'

This solved all my problems

More info at http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to resolve it, I preformed the following steps:

- Made sure the internal browser was able to connect to the internet.
- Window/preferences
- install/update
- available Software sites

click on each row that is checked, one at a time and at the bottom right side of the window it will tell you if the resource is available or not. If that resource is not available then uncheck it. I then added the following resource site and this was able to fix the error.
Name:Composite Marketplace Repository
Location:http://marketplace.eclipse.org/repo

HOPE THIS HELPS...

Comment: its all nice as a "look around and try these things..." answer, but the real answer that solved me this issue is: adding the line: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" under the line "-vmargs" in the file eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark and might not help but, have you tried the following:

> Can you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?
>
> - Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser.
> - Look up any normal adress, is it working?
>
> Can you connect to another update site? Try for example Eclipse Emma:
>   http://update.eclemma.org/ Do you see anything there?
>
> What are your proxy preferences? Go to Window -> preferences ->
>   General: Network connections.
>
> The active provider:
>
> > Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections. Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened
> >     without the use of a proxy server. Selecting Manual causes settings
> >     defined in Eclipse to be used. **On some platforms there is also a
> >     Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that
> >     were discovered in the OS to be used.**
>
> If internet is working fine outside of Eclipse, try changing to
>   Native. After that, try Direct.
>
> I have encountered problems where an update site would not load, then
>   I had to remove it and add it again. This forces Eclipse to reread the
>   contents of the site even if it has a cached copy. So, if you still
>   get no connection to the indigo update site, but everything else is
>   working, try that. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update:
>   Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site. Just
>   remember to copy the adress so you can add it again.

This is a copy and paste from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo).

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded browser works but updates will not work you might just be using a 32 bit Java on a 64 bit eclipse. Download the 32-bit version and see if that helps. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and nothing here worked.  What I found the problem to be was an issue with the versions of openjdk and oracle-java...as a result I installed all versions from 6-8...I'm not sure which one fixed the issue but after installing all of them the problem was resolved.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I checked my proxy setting for all the browsers which was installed ......... One of the browser(IE 8 for my case )  was using the proxy setting  to execute the testing sites of the company ........... 
I unchecked that one ......... restarted my eclipse  and now its working fine ..........

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:
Window → Preferences → Install/Update → Available software Site
edit the problematic sites-> remove the 's' from 'https' on the site lines!
using Luna.

Answer (score 0):

this is reference of

[Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo)

Can you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?

Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser.
Look up any normal adress, is it working?
Can you connect to another update site? Try for example Eclipse Emma: http://update.eclemma.org/ Do you see anything there?

What are your proxy preferences? Go to Window -> preferences -> General: Network connections.

The active provider:

Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections. Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened without the use of a proxy server. Selecting Manual causes settings defined in Eclipse to be used. On some platforms there is also a Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used.
If internet is working fine outside of Eclipse, try changing to Native. After that, try Direct.

I have encountered problems where an update site would not load, then I had to remove it and add it again. This forces Eclipse to reread the contents of the site even if it has a cached copy. So, if you still get no connection to the indigo update site, but everything else is working, try that. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site. Just remember to copy the adress so you can add it again.

As suggested in a comment below by @lostiniceland, this is a simpler way to achieve the above:

Goto Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry and click the "Reload" button to the right. This is sometimes also helpful when you have a local updatesite for testing custom plugins

Answer (score 0):

My Eclipse Installation:

- SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.
- Eclipse Neon 64-bit
- Oracle JDK jdk1.8.0_51 64-bit

I worked out and followed many of the suggestions in the web and nothing helped.
Except that one:

- In eclipse Go to "Window -> preferences -> General: Network connections" and set the "Aktiv Source" to "Native"
- Exit eclipse
- In the shell prompt, type
- "*export http_proxy=http://proxy-rzf:8080*" (your own proxy server and port)
- invoke eclipse

DONE!!!

If you then go to the eclipse "Network connections" settings you will see something like the image:
[image: eclipse proxy settings added through the shell "export" Statement]

I hope i could help somebody with that. It cost me a lot of hours searching and trying.