# Eclipse Juno can't find repositories under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, repository, eclipse-juno

I have a problems with Eclipse Juno 64 under Windows 8 64: it can't see repositories, neither Maven, not eclipse's itself like http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

It say an error

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/compositeContent.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/compositeContent.xml.
Cannot assign requested address: connect
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Eclipse IDE - Repository Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771612/java-eclipse-ide-repository-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Edit `eclipse.ini` and add:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Also, if you are tring to use the android SDK edit the android.bat file (Located under : ...\android-sdk\tools)
locate `call %java_exe` ” and add

```
“-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true”.
```

It should look like:

```
call %java_exe% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true %REMOTE_DEBUG%
```

Comment: I just made those changes but it still can't find the packages