# Eclipse Repositories fail "Unable to read repository at"

Tags: eclipse

I generally don't use Eclipse, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but I've spent several hours going over this and can't find a problem.

I needed a plugin for Eclipse (PigEditor or PigPen) and attempted to install it via repository, this failed with the error below. When it wouldn't install, I downloaded the .zip version, extracted the archive, found the folder containing features and plugins directory and tried installing it. This also failed. I also tried a PigPen .jar and it wasn't picked up at all when placing it into the plugins folder.

I noticed along the way that I received a bunch of error messages where it looked like Eclipse was trying to fetch dependencies. For example...

```
Error
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3.
java.io.IOException: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 is not a valid repository location.
```

That -should- be a valid repository location, it's listed about halfway down [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites). This unable to read repository is the same error that I got when trying to install the previous plugin from repository.

I then went to the Preferences -> Available Software Sites and tried all of the default installed repositories. There were 2 checked (the one listed above, and http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler) and 2 unchecked (http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates and http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/updates). I hit reload on any of those and receive the same error message as above.

I can access websites from the internal browser. I've also tried changing my Network Connections preference to "Direct".

Really all I care about is getting a working Pig plugin, so I'll accept that as an answer. I'm getting the feeling though that my failure to get any repositories is a symptom of a bigger problem (and I really want to know what's going on), so if you have troubleshooting steps I'm willing to try anything.

Sites I'm trying to get the Pig editor from:
https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigPen
http://romainr.github.io/PigEditor/
https://github.com/romainr/PigEditor

Comment: I can confirm that updates/repositories are being blocked by our firewall. This shouldn't be happening if Eclipse uses port 80, which from my understanding it should be. If anyone knows a way to ensure that only port 80 is used, knows a way to force it to use port 80, or can tell me for sure exactly what ports are used by Eclipse that may help solve my problems. In the mean time I'll keep digging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo[enter link description here][1]

Comment: please refer this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo

Answer (score 3):

Solution :

Open up .exe eclipse file from command promtp followed by command -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

or

changed in eclipse.init file.

Comment: that fix didn't work for me but i did discover that the site I was trying to install from was being blocked by my companies firewall as a "parked site"