# Installinng SVN in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, editor

Can someone please guide me to install `svn` in `eclipse luna`.

I am searching for steps but not getting proper result.

need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive) Stack Overflow question, there are two Eclipse plug-ins for Subversion: [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). Regarding which plug-in to use, the answers on that question are thoroughly informational. For installing Subversive, instructions can be found on the Eclipse website [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php), and instructions for installing Subclipse can be found [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=3857AF8C4A8356B64C7B005264424EA2?pageID=p4wYuA). If you are having trouble installing Subclipse, the instructions for Subversion are much more detailed in the general process of installing Eclipse plug-ins.

From the installation instructions for Subversive:

> 1. Run Eclipse and select Help > Install New Software... from the main
>      menu.
> 2. On the dialog that appears, select a pre-configured simultaneous
>      release update site in the Work with combo-box. For example, for the
>      Luna release, select the "Luna -
>      http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" update site.
> 3. Wait a few seconds until the content of the selected update site is displayed
>      under the combo-box.
> 4. Expand the Collaboration group and select the
>      Subversive features that you would like to install. Certain Subversive
>      features are required if you want to work with SVN, others are
>      optional and offer some additional functionality. You can skip the
>      optional features, if you wish.
> 5. Follow the next steps to install the
>      selected Subversive features using the standard plug-in installation
>      procedure. Reboot Eclipse after installation is complete.

Comment: i am getting `Unable to read repository` error when trying to connect. i changed network setting from `native` to `direct` still no effect. internal browser is working properly.

Comment: Can you be more specific? At exactly what point of the process does this happen, and are you installing Subversive or Subclipse?

Comment: while installing new software. i am trying to install `Subclipse`. Even predefine `luna` site is unable to open. i tried to reload it from `windows->preferences->install/update->available software sites` still getting same error

Comment: I found the answer to another Stack Overflow question with the same problem that may resolve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo/7722815#7722815

Comment: :D i went through that. but not working for me. looks like antivirus issue which blocking contents. but before some days i installed `smarty` without any errors.

Comment: You can also try the third option on http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php which is to install via the Eclipse Marketplace client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67404/discussion-between-sartaglo-and-shri).

Comment: Hi, I installed Subversive. Provided access through antivirus.