# eclipse mars/luna unable to read repository

Tags: eclipse, repository

I can't use the default repositories with eclipse mars. For example the `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/`. There is no problem with the proxy. I can reach `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/` with the internal web browser of eclipse. The problem is that it always tries to connect to the url `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/compositeContent.xml` which does not exist (getting 404 opening it in the browser). I really don't know why.

The error is:

```
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/compositeContent.xml
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

EDIT: Tried out Eclipse Luna, same problem.

Comment: Shot in the dark: add `-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` (second part on a new line) to your eclipse.ini file?

Comment: What JDK/JRE version are you using?

Comment: yes, got it in a new line, jdk, jre going to tell you jdk and jre version tomorrow

Comment: C:\Users\xxxxxxxx>java -version

java version "1.8.0_40"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

@approxiblue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo           this may helps you.

Comment: I am sorry, already tried that. @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: @thefiloe Yesterday I downloaded "eclipse mars for java developers" and all works for me. Maybe you need to update your eclipse. I have: Windows 8, java 1.7.0_10. I can to "install new software" via `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/`. I checked it.

Comment: I've downloaded it a few days ago @home. Everything works fine. I know that. But not in my company.

Comment: @thefiloe Can you to disable firewall of your company??? Maybe this firewall blocks the port which eclipse use for updates.

Comment: hahaha, probably not. but we'll have a look at it.

Comment: @thefiloe What is the OS you have???? Try to `service iptables stop` if you have Linux-base operation system.

Comment: Same problem here. I can't even open the URL in an external browser. Do we work at the same company? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is 'something' wrong with the repository where this update is located and nothing wrong with your network connection or proxy.

What is this 'something' - If you look at this link https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/p2_index ('What happens if I get it Wrong' section) - It says that if the p2.index file has an incorrect entry *specifying compositeContent.xml where the repository is a content.xml will cause p2 to only look for compositeContent.xml and never look for the content.xml*.

*Maybe* this is what is happening in your case and since eclipse is not getting the file it is throwing the error which you are seeing.

Way ahead will be to - contact the eclipse.org on their forum/JIRA to point it out and get the p2.index file corrected.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace says, you don't connect. As you don't make a connection with a file, a missing file could not cause the problem. The Native proxy provider does not work for you.

I had to switch to Manual proxy configuration and delete the (empty) SOCKS entry from the proxy configuration in order to get Mars to properly connect through our firewall.

Comment: i've already switched to manual, but how can i delete the socks entry? And just by the way, I can connect to the repo `https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/mars/` but not to the default repos of eclipse.

Comment: @thefiloe Okay, back at work I could check my settings. Just hit the 'Clear' button on the SOCKS entry. That other repos work is strange though. I can guarantee you, Mars and the repo `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars` work fine here, so it's not their server. I think there is no other solution than to capture the problem with Wireshark or ask your IT department.

Comment: @thefiloe Checking Wireshark, the first request Eclipse does, the very moment you select "Install new software", before even selecting the repo, is to get `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/compositeContent.jar`. You should check in Wireshark if this succeeds or not. The .xml might be a fallback, if the first already fails.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" and try again.

If that does not work, you could goto the following link download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/ and click "Show Directory Contents" and download each file using "Save link as" and add them manually to eclipse.

Comment: well but I need to "contact all update sites" because I need some of the their packages => tried it out, does not work.

Comment: if you have no other go, you could try the second option and save each file in the same directory structure as the site. Then use it to install from the local. This is a hard workaround though.