# Why don't install genymotion plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, genymotion

I try install genymotion plugin for eclipse But get error like below image.Can i install offline ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should check this post, could be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uncheck Group items by category in install new software window and solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

same problem 
when i try to install Genymotion i get an Error like this

> Unable to connect to repository http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/content.xml
>   Unable to connect to repository http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/content.xml
>   Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Eclipse website is blocked for iranian users.Use vpn ,freegate or siphon .If  your problem don't solved uncheck Group items by category in install new software window .I hope helpful

Comment: thanks , problem is about my iran ip , i used freegate , it solve my problem and now i can get genymotion plugin for eclipse . we are Poor peaple in technology

Comment: why you saying to our freedom peaple ? we are poor really