# No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I'm trying to install the m2Eclipse plugin, but when I try to add the site under available software sites I am getting this error:

> "No repository found at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"

With this stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

This also occurs for any other repositories I try to add.

Based on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo) some fixes are:

1. Fix proxy settings and verify you are able to connect to the
   internet with eclipses browser
2. Remove and add site again (or
   Reload)
3. Start eclipse with these properties: -vmargs
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
4. Deleting the cache directory "\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache"

I was able to do (1) Fix proxy settings and connect to the repository in the browser.  It is even able to connect to the repository through the browser:

[image: successful internal browser]

But none of these solutions allowed me to install software when going through the Help -> Install new Software -> process.  Does anyone have any more information or troubleshooting advice for this issue?

Comment: Did you got a fix for this problem?. I am trying to do this on Eclipse neon (4.6).

Comment: Any news on this? Having the same issue with Photon, version 4.8

Answer (score 31):

Solved it by changing the repository address to:

https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest

You can change it in Help -> "Install new Software..." -> "Manage" button. Clicking on it will take you to the Software Sites management dialog. Here you can add, delete or edit software Sites.

Comment: How and where to change this URL?

Comment: @MehrajMalik the dialog for "Install new Software..." (help menu) has a "Manage" button. Clicking on it will take you to the Software Sites management dialog. Here you can add, delete or edit Sofware Sites.

Comment: OMG, you saved a thousand year of my life. This answer should be marked as accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Go to eclipse->help->Install new softwares->add->https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest and press enter
then it will show Maven integration for eclipse. Kindly click on next and install it.
Relaunch the eclipse after installing. you can able to see maven option

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by decreasing the selenium version from 4.1.4 to 4.1.3