# Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/compositeContent.xml

Tags: eclipse

I am getting the below error while trying to "install a new software" from eclipse-Luna.

Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/compositeContent.xml
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/compositeContent.xml
Connection timed out: connect

Can someone please helpme in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

First, please be sure you are using **Eclipse Luna** to install software from Luna Repo.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/compositeContent.xml
is not reachable and gives **404 Not Found**;

Use eclipse marketplace or work with [Eclipse Luna Repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/)

[image: Eclipse Marketplace]

[image: Luna Repo]
Still have same problem check your eclipse version.

Comment: I didnt understand what do you mean by "First you should use Eclipse Luna"...can you pls explain it clearly?

Comment: Maybe you are using mars or kepler. Checking is good idea :). If sentence looks rough, sorry

Comment: No probs...It's Luna dude..Btw, how do I resolve it with eclipse market place?

Comment: I added it, maybe you want to search via marketplace. And I've just seen a previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722815/517134) for Indigo. It may help you, too.