# Eclipse luna shows error "Unable to read repository at"

Tags: java

I am getting the below error when I tried to install tomcat server from Eclipse Marketplace at Eclipse Luna(eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32[4.4]) on IE11 in Windows 7.

---

Unable to read repository at http://tomcatplugin.sf.net/update/content.xml.
           Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

---

Can anyone please help me on this to get resolve.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more details on what system you are running Eclipse on and the exact version of Eclipse.

Comment: Hi, am using eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32 on IE 11

Comment: Please add that information into your question, you can always hit the "edit" button. Also which Operationsystem?

Comment: Also: Clicking your provided link leads to an error, that the site does not exist. Maybe you could try to use the latest Eclipse Oxygen and see if the error persists?

Comment: I have added details as you suggested and comes to the version of eclipse, only this eclipse version I'm supposed to work in my workplace.

Comment: To add more : I have another set-up which already done 1 year ago, but when I try the same now am getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

The repository has migrated to https (it is no longer accessible by http), and uses TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2, that are protocols not enabled by default in JDK 1.7.
You must start eclipse with JDK 1.8 or above. Edit `eclipse.ini` and add the next lines just before `-vmargs` whith your JDK path (more details in [eclipse.ini wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)):

```
-vm
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you could try, but the solution, that I deem to be relevant in this case comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo/7722815#19789426).

- Deleting the cache directory `\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache`
- Refreshing the repositories.

  - Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry
  - Click the "Reload"

Comment: Can you add into your question what kind of solutions you already tried, and which did not work? Also a short "thank you" is always nice if somebody tries to help you with your problem. ;)

Comment: Once I have deleted the Cache directory, I tried to reload the Available Software Site but I couldn't get the Reload button/option as enabled

Comment: Check if you are able to connect to eclipse market place url (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) from browser. If its working then the issue is because of proxy server using in your network. We have to update eclipse with proxy server details used in our network.

Go to :- Windows-> Preference -> General -> Network Connections.

enter image description here

And edit HTTP ,with proxy details.

enter image description here

Click OK

Done.


shareimprove this answer
 

answered Aug 21 '14 at 9:47 



 
Ajil Mohan 
4,7911917

Comment: Well I don't see that is related to proxy server yet, because the link you provided does not even work at all. It cannot be resolved. Show your Eclipse software is pointing to the wrong location of repository. Sou you need to update that location to the correct one.

Comment: But when I tried to access the link which i provided is takes me to one web page there i could see the updation acailable. So, i have tried to update/install it says that it is not supported

Comment: you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?
•Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser. 
•Look up any normal adress, is it working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo

Comment: Better the above link, i have followed all the solutions which mentioned there

Comment: Please add all the things that your have tried so far in the Question and give a detailed information on what went wrong and how exactly you tried it.

Comment: My Problem solved, I have installed manually by using the steps in the below link :)

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html

Answer (score 0):

probably because of the proxy issue, you may want to check and set it from windows->preference->network,
change to direct, and then try again
[image]