# Missing requirement not available as Osgi bundle

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

Hello I am working on a feature based  Xtext/Picto RCP(similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmUrTlzqCXc, where I try to  get the following error when I maven install it:

```
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.epsilon.picto 2.3.0.202104221823 requires 'osgi.bundle; com.atlassian.commonmark 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I already got the tipp to try this: https://xn--lubisoft-0za.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/ but
com.atlassian.commonmark is not available as  Osgi bundle and therefore does not solve the issue. I hardly think its impossible to use Picto in a RCP so is there a workaround, maybe telling Picto to already install all its needed artifacts? Thank you for any idea!

Comment: There is always the possibility to create your own Eclipse/OSGi plugin/bundle: _File > New > Other...: Plug-in Development > Plug-in from Existing JAR Archive_.

Comment: [Eclipse Orbit](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.orbit) seems to have some commonmark plug-ins.

Comment: What greg-449 says. Does the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20210825222808/repository`](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20210825222808/repository) work for you (see [here](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/))?

Comment: yes thank you that did the job! Follow up question: Now I get the errror **The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display cannot be resolved** The type is imported in my first plugin project and org.eclipse.swt should be part of the p2 eclipse sdk repo so shouldnt that be recognized right away? Nonetheless I tried to add this to the dependenices of the plugin project but the artifact cannot be find. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by _first plugin project_? Do you have a second plugin? If the second plugin depends on the first plugin, than it can access the exported packages of the first plugin and the reexported dependencies of the first plugin. Does your target platform include also the platform dependent SWT fragments?