# Connection refused when trying to connect to mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to connect to mysql database using hibernate from the cfg file as

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" 
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">
            10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
            update</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->

        <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>





   private static SessionFactory factory;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
                ex.fillInStackTrace();
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
```

Though my connection-string,username,password are correct and the same are working fine in other project with basic jdbc connection, But when I try it using hibernate I am getting this error on console

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hibernate.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at com.hibernate.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:19)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at com.hibernate.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:16)
```

And yes the database server is up and running but the connections from this hibernate application are refused

Comment: Are you created the password for test db. If not create password for test database

Comment: There is no mention about hibernate is trying to connect in your stack trace (just configuring).My guess is that your XML parser is trying to connect somewhere to get DTD/XSD for validation.Can you provide full stacktrace? Also check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114046/hibernate-error-possibly-with-dtd-declaration

Comment: @udaykiranpulipati : I have created the password already

Comment: @rkosegi : check the edit I have added the full stacktrace

Comment: @Rishabh where you place hibernate.cfg.xml. If it is not in src root folder, Place it there.

Comment: @udaykiranpulipati : it is in the src root folder

Comment: Try to put it in "WEB-INF/classes" directory

Comment: @mareckmareck the configuration file is found that's not the problem. The problem seems to be the DTDResolver. Maybe Doctype and used library don't match. Old Libraries used the namespace `http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/`newer ones (3.6) use `http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/`

Comment: verify Your active provider like here [eclipse-prefrences-network-connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456480/eclipse-prefrences-network-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the xml parser is trying to access the schema file which is specified in the configuration file. Can the box, where you are running your program, access the internet?

Here is some additional information:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=949031

Comment: Hibernate can resolve the DTDs locally (without a network connection). See for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301294/cant-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml-while-offline